# How bootstrapper authenticate with server?

Tags: authentication, wix, bootstrapper

I built a bootstrapper for the windows installer (*.msi) file for an application. In the chain element,

i used `<msipackage DownloadUrl=http://... />`. Here is my code, `

```
<Bundle Name="xyz" Version="1.0.0.1" Manufacturer="abc" UpgradeCode="*"
      IconSourceFile="\..\Edit.ico">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLargeLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
    LogoFile="C:\Users\Pictures\Saved Pictures\Edit.jpg"
    LicenseFile="C:\Users\Documents\License.rtf"
    LogoSideFile="C:\Users\Pictures\Saved Pictures\Wait.jpg"
    ShowVersion="yes"
    ThemeFile="E:\Prcatice\Dev\New\CustomTheme.xml"
    LocalizationFile="E:\Prcatice\Dev\New\localTheme.wxl" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
        <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
        <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
  <MsiPackage Id="asd" Cache="yes" Compressed="no" SourceFile="E:\Prcatice\Dev\New\Setup\bin\Release\Setup.msi" Vital="yes" Visible="no" 
              DownloadUrl="http://localhost/Dev/Setup/Setup.msi" />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

`
I used DownloadUrl to fetch the msi file from the server while installing.It works very nice.

What i wanted is, I want to know how this bootstrapper is authenticating with the server provided in DownloadUrl attribute. How to make sure that the setup downloaded is from the given link or the server. I'm asking this question because, it is possible to redirect the request to some other server. If someone redirects the request to some other server and a virus or a malware is downloaded then it will be problem.

Is there any documentation available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Web servers hosting content should host with anonymous access.  That said,  WiX can check the SHA hash / checksum or authenticode signature of a file to make sure it hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer.